# Web Service to get Books details

Tags: web-services

Is there any publicly available web service where I could get book details. Given a book title it should return the ISBN number, author, year of publication etc.

Comment: Hmm, gee this got downvoted, but it doesn't seem *off topic* to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon has data services that allow you to search for books.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012082/aws-ecs-api-itemlookup-get-items-ean-salesrank-by-browsenode

I think they are still free to use. You need to register, and also the user agreement says you may use these APIs only if you drive commerce traffic back to Amazon's site.

---

Also see OpenLibrary
http://openlibrary.org/, http://openlibrary.org/developers/api

and  ISBNdb
http://isbndb.com/data-intro.html

and a related question

[How to get ISBN number from a book title and author programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893908/how-to-get-isbn-number-from-a-book-title-and-author-programmatically)

Comment: First link is dead.